# Why is my jQuery not allowing me to toggle classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of custom Chevron elements that I'm going to use as buttons on my site. I've managed to set up the jQuery so that the clicked chevron/button is given a class="selected" which I then use to add custom styles. If I click any other chevron then the selected class is removed from the first chevron and added to the last chevron that was clicked. All of this works fine. I have another link that can be clicked to remove the class from all of the chevrons. What I'm trying to do now is to enable the .toggle(Class) function on jQuery so that I can also remove the class="selected" by clicking the same element twice.

My jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
$('#chevrons > ul > li > a').click( function(){
    $('#chevrons .selected').removeClass('selected');
    $('#show-all').removeAttr("style");
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
   });
});

$(function () {
    $('#show-all').click( function(){
      $('#chevrons .selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).css('color', '#FECF2A');
    });
});
```

I've tried the toggle without the rows:

```
$('#chevrons .selected').removeClass('selected');
    $('#show-all').removeAttr("style");
```

And it works fine. I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that the jQuery would execute line-by-line and therefore the last thing to execute. But perhaps the first line above is removing the "selected" attribute from all of the chevrons and then the last line will only ever add the class.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle for this code

Comment: I am not sure but maybe by doing this `$('#chevrons .selected').removeClass('selected');` you are not allowing that chevron to be selected by that jQuery selector anymore, maybe changing to `$(this).removeClass('selected');` will fix it...

Comment: Feels like there may be a conflick with the `removeClass('selected')` and `toggleClass('selected')`, since they target the same elements.

Comment: Yes, if you first remove all `selected` classes then the current element can't have that class, so `.toggleClass()` will always only add it. You need to split the functionality into two and add the class only if the element didn't already have it.

Comment: Thanks @Juhana, I thought that might be the case. Any idea how I'd split it in two?

Comment: `if( $(this).hasClass('selected') { $(this).removeClass('selected') } else { ... }`

Comment: @Zoinks10 you just had to select jQuery in the frameworks & extensions select and your fiddle just works fine ;)

Comment: +1 for that amazing looking JSFiddle. I have added my fix below to your JSFiddle as well to confirm it works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/qsnkqhp8/1/ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/oqs4nycj/1/

Just exclude the clicked item from the class removal using `not()`:

```
    $('#chevrons .selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
```

Applying this fix to your own JSFiddle (looks very cool by the way) you get this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qsnkqhp8/1/

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help. I promise I'm not using those colors in my actual application!

Answer (score 0):

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gopj0hyj/

**Edit**. I did not read the question carefully enough. Sorry. I have edited the code to deselect by clicking twice.

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    // Variables are your friends - the $ preface tells us its a jQuery object
    var $chevrons = $("#chevrons");
    var $buttons = $chevrons.find('a');
    var $show_all = $('#show_all');

    // We bind a handler to the parent $chevrons element
    // this is good for performance 
    // It will also bind the handler to elements dynamically added with ajax.
    $chevrons.on('click', 'a', function(e){
        var $old_selection = $buttons.filter('.selected');
        var $clicked = $(this);

        // Ensure that no button is selected
        $buttons.removeClass('selected');

        // Checks if button already was selected.
        if ($clicked.get(0) !== $old_selection.get(0)) {
            // select the clicked button
            $clicked.addClass('selected');
        }

        $show_all.removeClass('active');
        // prevents the browser from scrolling to top.
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $show_all.on('click', function(){
        $buttons.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Clicking the selected item does not toggle the selection off (which is the specified aim)

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I did´nt read the question carefully enough and missed that part. Will edit answer.

Comment: Thanks again @TrueBlueAussie, not at the top of my game today.